# Alternative to scipy.optimize.minimize constrained optimization?

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, constraints

I am interested in finding optimized parameters of a model (by minimizing the model's output with the known value). The parameters I am interested in finding have bounds and they are also constrained by an inequality that looks like `1 - sum(x_par) >= 0`, where `x_par` is a list of some of the parameters out of the total parameter list. I have used [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://scipy.optimize.minimize) to minimize this problem with different methods (such as `COBYLA` and `SLSQP`), but the fitting performance by this function is quite poor and the error is generally above 50%.

I have noticed that [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and [`scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) work very well in terms of fitting the given values, but these functions do not allow constraints on parameters. I am looking for an alternative in python to optimize my problem that allows constraining parameters and can do a better job in fitting the given curve/values than [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://scipy.optimize.minimize).

Comment: gurobi is great for linear or quadratic functions.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [lmfit](https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py) useful. This module is a wrapper around many of the scipy.optimized routines (including `leastsq`, `differential_evolution`, most of the scaler minimizers) that replaces all variables with `Parameter` objects that can be fixed or free, have bounds applied, or be constrained as mathematical expressions of other Parameters, all independent of the method used to solve the minimization problem. There is also a `Model` class to support many curve fitting problems, and support for improved analysis of confidence intervals for parameters.

With some care, inequality constraints can be applied, as is discussed briefly at
http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html#using-inequality-constraints .

Comment: I am curious if the way parameters are defined (using an object) makes this package unsuitable for problems that require optimizing a large number of parameters? For instance, I would know in advance how many parameters the problem needs to optimize, but I can't specify 'definition' of each parameter through an object because of the complexity in terms of a large number of parameters. In that respect, `scipy.optimize.minimize` is flexible because the input parameter can just be expanded as `x1, ..xn = x[0], ...x[n]`

Comment: Since lmfit wraps scipy.optimize.minimize, it should be able to handle similarly complex problems.  Lmfit keeps the Parameters in an ordered dictionary so that you don't have to assign meaning to the index.  This might seem like a small benefit, but it allows the user to conveniently turn any Parameter from varied to fixed without having to rewrite the objective function.   But if you want, you can name the parameters "1", "2", ..... ;)

Comment: Hi...how can I implement the constraint `1 - sum(x_par) >= 0`? I am not sure how the sum function can be accounted through an expression, which is the general way of accounting inequality constraint as suggested in the link you provided. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do that's not already documented, and am not eager to have such a discussion in an SO comment section. Please use lmfit mailing list (preferred) or an actual SO question.

Comment: I am not getting any different result than what I get through scipy.optimize.minimize, which is not surprising given that lmfit is only a wrapper around different methods of scipy.optimize.minimize. If that's the case, may I know why you suggested this as an alternative that may produce better results?